# Failing to create package with manifoldjs

Tags: javascript, npm

I am eager to try out the new [ManifoldJS](http://www.manifoldjs.com/) that Microsoft announced at Build 2015, but I am struggling. I have put up a  basic site on http://powertalks.azurewebsites.net/. It is a HTML- and JS- app using Angular and TypeScript. I have also published a manifest.json file, so all should be good to go.

When I try to generate a package online from: http://www.manifoldjs.com/generator, it says it is generating, but nothing happens. Looking at the dev tools, I see that an 500 Internal Server Error pops up. Trying the command line yields no results either. It starts to generate the packages, but returns with a new error:

```
"Command failed: 'C:\Users\FirstName'  is not recognized as an internal or external command".
```

I should point out that my manifoldjs file is installed on 'C:\Users\FirstName LastName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\manifoldjs', so might be something to do with the space in the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been addressed (https://github.com/manifoldjs/ManifoldJS/issues/57) and the fix will be available in version v0.2.1.